# Resources about Excel tables and structured references?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm new to Excel-post-2000, and I'd like to learn more about how to use tables (formerly lists) and structured references.

Can anyone point me to some good treatments of this topic that go beyond the help?

(For example, there are numerous full books about just pivot tables. Something like that for using table would be ideal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links that may be helpful:

- [Structured referencing in Microsoft Office Excel 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb833052%28office.11%29.aspx)
- [Using structured references with Excel tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101556861033.aspx)
- [Want to become a Data God? Learn Excel Data Tables](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/10/data-tables/)
- [Working with Tables in Excel 2007](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007tables.asp?AllComments=True)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the Microsoft links, but hadn't yet sifted through the Excel blogs.